# Disk image of OS + Recovery partition?

Tags: disk-utility, dmg, diskutil

I'm working with multiple OS X versions frequently and I'd like to have an image which contains a particular OS version's system partition and its recovery partition. Is this possible? (the disk where these partitions are, contains several other partitions which I don't want, so full-disk image is not an option)

I'm guessing this cannot be done as a single-step process, so I've already created an appropriately-sized sparsebundle image with GPT layout:

`hdiutil create -size 35g -layout GPTSPUD -type SPARSEBUNDLE /path/to/new_image.dmg`

The next step would be to copy the relevant partition onto this image, but I don't know how to do this. My Linux experience tells me the partitioning utility should be the place to look for this, but I don't see anything in `diskutil`'s manual which looks like it does what I want.

Hints/ideas?

Comment: After going through [Apple's KB](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202841) and [this post](http://www.dmitry-dulepov.com/2011/09/how-to-create-mac-os-x-lion-recovery.html), these are my observations:  


- The extra partitions are added in a separate step by using `diskutil`'s `resizeVolume` command, which can add partitions in the free space after the partition being worked on.  


- The Recovery partition differs only in its GUID type in the GPT table. Using the `gpt` command, removing the partition and re-adding it with proper GUID achieves the desired state.

Comment: Also interesting, `asr`, at least the version in OS X 10.11, will restore both the system partition _and_ the recovery immediately following. If one is starting with a disk which already has both OS and partition, then `asr` should be enough to do everything.  
So really, the real issue is that the GUI Disk Utility creates images of partitions and single-filesystem images which don't hold the accompanying recovery partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Starting from a working setup

A working setup is disk, or full-disk image with multiple partitions (*FDI* hereafter), where the OS and its recovery partition is known to be correct, most likely because it was created by the OS Installer. As mentioned in the comment, `asr` is enough to handle copying both partitions in this case.

Assuming the source OS and recovery partitions are `disk3s11` and `disk3s12`, respectively, I recommend the following procedure:

1. Shrink the OS partition to its minimum size. This isn't necessary, but I suggest doing it when you can never be sure if the user's target partition will be as big as the one you're using.

   ```
   $ diskutil resizeVolume disk3s11 limits

   ... (minimum size will be mentioned here) ...

   $ diskutil resizeVolume disk3s11 24GB
   ```
2. Create appropriately-sized temporary FDI as a sparsebundle. **Remember, the Recovery takes extra 650 MB over the system partition, and EFI takes *another* 210 MB.** So I'll add an extra GB to the size used in step 1 just to be safe. The catch here is, `hdiudil` support **only binary** prefixes (1024 for `k`, etc.). In this example, 25 GB = 23.29 GiB.

   ```
   $ hdiutil create -layout GPTSPUD -type SPARSEBUNDLE -size 23.29g /tmp/temp_FDI

   created: /tmp/temp_FDI.sparsebundle
   ```
3. Attach the image without mounting it (it would fail, since the partition was not formatted). Take note of the `/dev/` entry for the Apple_HFS partition.

   ```
   $ hdiutil attach /tmp/temp_FDI.sparsebundle -nomount

   /dev/disk5              GUID_partition_scheme           
   /dev/disk5s1            EFI                             
   /dev/disk5s2            Apple_HFS
   ```
4. Run `asr` with the image's empty partition as the target. You'll have to enter full path to `/dev/...` entries. Also, since the source is a physical disk, elevated privileges are necessary. You should see the tool finish with **2 rows** of *Restoring...* progress.

   ```
   $ sudo asr restore --source /dev/disk3s11 --target /dev/disk5s2 --erase  --noverify

       Validating target...done
       Validating source...done
       Erase contents of /dev/disk5s2 ()? [ny]: y
       Validating sizes...done
       Restoring  ....10....20....30....40....50....60....70....80....90....100
       Restoring  ....10....20....30....40....50....60....70....80....90....100
   ```
5. Finally, create a compressed read-only image from the sparsebundle. Use the sparsebundle's "whole disk" `/dev/` entry (`/dev/disk5`).

   ```
   $ hdiutil create -format ULFO -srcdevice /dev/disk5 -o /tmp/OS_X_10.11-combined_FDI2.dmg

   ...
   Elapsed Time:  2m 33.743s
   File size: 8000565446 bytes, Checksum: CRC32 $5D496986
   Sectors processed: 48842670, 38032196 compressed
   Speed: 120.8Mbytes/sec
   Savings: 68.0%
   created: /tmp/OS_X_10.11-combined_FDI2.dmg
   ```

   You may wish to use `UDZO` format if you need your image to be compatible with older versions of OS X and their respective Recovery environments (ULFO was only introduced in 10.11).

---

## Working from the ground up

It is possible to assemble a "working setup" from single-partition images (images which don't have partition table, and therefore no hint for `asr` that a particular partition is a Recovery; *SPI* hereafter). The procedure is not for the faint of heart.

I'm going to assume that I have a compressed, read-only SPIs of both the system partition, and the recovery partition. Shrinking the partitions to minimum size is a whole another can of worms, where using a full-blown `UDRW` image seems unavoidable. Feel free to suggest a simpler solution.

1. With that in mind, do a pre-shrink of the system partition image. Readonly image can only be shrunk with a shadow.

   ```
   $ hdiutil resize -sectors min  OS_X_10.11-system.dmg -shadow /tmp/pre-shrink.shadow
   ```
2. Check the image size, then attach it

   ```
   $ hdiutil imageinfo OS_X_10.11-system.dmg -shadow /tmp/pre-shrink.shadow

   ...
       Total Bytes: 27648868352

   $ hdiutil attach OS_X_10.11-system.dmg -shadow /tmp/pre-shrink.shadow -nomount

   ...
   /dev/disk7
   ```

The size is about 27.65 GB.

1. Create a sparse image big enough to hold the system and recovery partitions in full size - AFAICT, SPIs cannot be resized and that must be done inside an FDI. With extra space needed for EFI and recovery, we'll need 28.6 GB = 26.64 GiB.

   ```
   $ hdiutil create -layout GPTSPUD -type SPARSEBUNDLE -size 26.64g /tmp/temp_FDI
   $ hdiutil attach /tmp/temp_FDI.sparsebundle -nomount
   /dev/disk5              GUID_partition_scheme           
   /dev/disk5s1            EFI                             
   /dev/disk5s2            Apple_HFS
   ```
2. Do an `asr` restore from the system SPI's `/dev/` node into the sparsebundle's data partition.

   ```
   $ asr restore --source /dev/disk7 --target /dev/disk5s2 --erase --noverify
   ```
3. Now, check the minimum size of the partition using `diskutil`. Then use `resizeVolume` to shrink the partition *and* create the recovery partition in a single step.

   ```
   $ diskutil mount disk5s2
   $ diskutil resizeVolume disk5s2 limits

   ... (minimum size will be mentioned here) ...

   $ diskutil resizeVolume disk5s2 24GB JHFS+ Recovery %recovery% Free\ Space dummy 1m
   ```
4. Restore the recovery SPI into the new  partition on the FDI. It will probably get mounted, so unmount it. You can work with the image directly.

   ```
   $ asr restoreexact --source /path/to/OS_X_10.11-recovery.dmg --target /dev/disk5s3 --erase --noverify

   ...
   $ diskutil umount disk5s3
   ```
5. Here's the tricky bit - dump the partition table using the `gpt` utility, taking note of the recovery partition's *start* and *size* values. Delete the record for the recovery partition, and re-add it with modified type GUID. You will know which record is for the recovery partition by the index ("disk5s**3**"), and by its size (shown here in 512 B sectors).

   ```
   $ gpt show disk5
   ...
      47546784    1269536      3  GPT part - "Recovery"
   ...
   $ gpt remove -i 3 disk5
   $ gpt add -b 47546784 -s 1269536 -t 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC disk5
   ```
6. Optional: I also recommend changing the partition name (set to "disk image" by default) to match the system partition's volume name.

   ```
   $ gpt label -i 2 -l "OS X 10.11" disk5
   ```
7. Now, since `hdiutil resize` doesn't work with sparsebundles the way we'd need, you can either:

   - Leave it at that. It's not like the free space consumes anything. Continue with step 5 in the *Working setup* scenario.
   - Convert the temp_FDI.sparsebundle image to UDRW, and try to properly shrink that. I haven't tested that and the need to write out the entire size image for this step makes the whole exercise pointless.
   - Treat the sparsebundle existing at this point as a disk with optimally-shrunk system, and perform the first scenario on it, skipping step 1. Ie. create *another* sparsebundle image, and run `asr`, which will this time copy both partitions into the new image, and convert *that* to ULFO image.

---

## Restoring

Steps for restoring from the created image:

1. Mount the image using

   ```
   # hdiutil attach /tmp/backup_image.dmg -nomount
   ```
2. Start the restore, either by:

   - Use the "Disk Utility" app, restoring from the partition in the backup_image to the partition on your drive (the one in Sierra *just works*, restoring the Recovery partition too: you will see two Restoring/Verifying steps)
   - Use `asr`, similarly as described above:

     `$ asr restore --source /dev/disk1s2 --target /dev/disk0s4 --erase  --noverify`